# Simple bootstrap working but doesnt look right

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

This is my first try using bootstrap. I am just trying to get a basic menu bar working. From what I see everything works fine, but just doesnt look ok. I tried to switch out the css with a new download, but still doesnt seem to fix anything.

This is the HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Test</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">

      <div class="row">
          <nav class="navbar">
            <div class="navbar-inner">
                <a href="#" class="brand">test</a>
              <ul class="nav">
                <li><a href="#">Item1</a></li>
                <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Item1</a></li>
                <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Item1</a></li>
                <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Connect<b class="caret"></b></a>

                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Item1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Item1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Item1</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>

              </ul>
            </div>
          </nav>
      </div>
    </div>


    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Nothing complex. Got the basic structure from Bootstrap website. Just added the new menu.

It looks like this

[image]

I have checked the CSS files to be in the right place and also the bootstrap js file.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Have a look at: http://getbootstrap.com/examples/starter-template/

Comment: you want the menu to be horizontal?

Comment: If it's working than whats the matter?

Comment: It looks like you have html for version 2 and css for version 3.

Comment: Yep. That's 2.x html and it doesn't work with Bootstrap 3 css. Go to GetBootstrap.com and get the new navbar html

Comment: Are you using any user defined styles ?

Comment: yeah, but not something that would affect bootstrap. I figure the answer is what @Christina has pointed out. I am using the classes for 2.x while the bootstrap css is for Bootstrap 3. They have new classes that I need to add along with the existing ones.

Comment: It's not just classes, the html is different too. There's no divider or inner and various other things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the class `navbar-brand` to the first 'a' tag

```
<a href="#" class="brand navbar-brand">test</a>
```

And add the class `navbar-nav` to the first 'ul' tag:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav ">
```

With these changes the example looks better.

I can't post images yet, but in the next link you can see how the example look after this changes:

[image]